# Trying to print postorder and inorder but dont know how to do it

Tags: java

Im trying to learn how to print in binary tree and  I understand how to do it for pre-order but cannot figure out how to do for post and in order way. I understand the difference between all of them but dont know how to implement it.

```
int key ;
Node left ;
Node right ;

public Node ( int x ) {
    payload = x ; 
}

public void printPreorder() {
    System.out.println(this.key);
    if (left != null) {
        this.left.printPreorder();
    }
    if (right != null) {
        this.right.printPreorder();
    }
}

public void printPostorder() {

}

public void printInorder() {
    System.out.println(this.key);   
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy, just move down the print statement. Once for in order, twice for post order.

It doesn't have a lot to do with Java, but with recursion. In pre-order what you do is: start from root and print it, go left, print. Go left until you can and print everything. Then start going right and print at each step. With this explanation try to figure out what happens in the other two cases I explained. Just try to narrate it as I wrote and you should be able to understand.

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: @JMm Did you succed?

Comment: Yes I did and also understand it

Answer (score 0):

So I noticed an issue with your inOrder method it should  be

```
public void printInorder() {
    if (left != null) {
        this.left.printInOrder();
    }
    System.out.println(this.key);
    if (right != null) {
        this.right.printInOrder();
    }
}
```

Right because with inorder you want to print lowest to highest. Print my left, print me, then print right.